# SQL Server - Indexed View with FOR JSON

Tags: json, sql-server

I'm testing different ways that I can implement CQRS. One of my test uses FOR JSON queries to bypass any type of ORM, much like described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2018/01/29/simplify-rest-api-development-modern-single-page-apps-sql-server/). Another implementation I wanted to test was, instead of creating the JSON data on-the-fly, to create an key-value type indexed view where the key is some identifier and the data is the JSON data created from the 'actual' data. For data stores that are updated sparingly but read frequently, this would seem like a smart thing to do. The problem is how to create the indexed view, something like the following.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JsonTest]
(
    [Number] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Date] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [Customer] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Price] [MONEY] NULL,
    [Quantity] [INT] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE VIEW dbo.CustomerOrders
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
(
    SELECT 
        customer,
        (SELECT 
             Customer AS AccountNumber,
             Number AS [Order.Number],
             Date AS [Order.Date],
             Price AS 'Item.UnitPrice',
             Quantity AS 'Item.Qty'
         FROM
             dbo.JsonTest
         WHERE
             Customer = j.Customer
         FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Orders')) AS data
    FROM
        dbo.JsonTest j);
```

The problem is you can't create an indexed view from a view with subqueries. When using FOR JSON the entire query result is converted to JSON. What I need is the ability to convert the data in some columns into JSON.

Comment: Not possible unless you start mucking about with triggers, and I don't recommend that. This is too difficult for the engine to do automatically; if such a thing were permitted it would effectively be required to redo the entire query if a single row was changed in any way. Consider just indexing `Customer` if it's not indexed already and see if that's already enough; the bottleneck will be reading the row data, not producing the JSON.

Comment: @Jeroen That's what I was afraid of. I was hoping an indexed view would give me a shortcut to a separate read store that gets automatically updated behind the scenes. A trigger would achieve the same thing but implementationwould be a bit more involved.